# schedule set Interval method for check a specific time in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval

I want to implement a method in react native which is execute in every 1 min and check the time is completed on not. for example i want to show a popup when 12:00 pm is completed. i just create a set interval method which is execute is every 1 min and check 12:00 complete or not. so please suggest the solution.

Comment: Why not using `setInterval`?

Comment: @ItayGanor i a using it but i unable to do that.please suggest solution if you can solve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setInterval for every 5 second render with React hook useEffect in React Native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542264/how-to-setinterval-for-every-5-second-render-with-react-hook-useeffect-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
const dateToCheck = new Date();
const App = () => {
  const [hasTimePassed, setHasTimePassed] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (new Date() > dateToCheck) {
        setHasTimePassed(true);
      }
    }, 60000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, []);
};
```