# Javascript - How to loop through an array over and over again in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine I have an array of objects like this:

```js
const items = [
    {name: "item 0"},
    {name: "item 1"},
    {name: "item 2"}
]
```

And a component like this:

```
const [currentItemIndex, setCurrentItemIndex] = useState(0)

setInterval(function () {
   if (currentItemIndex < 3) {
      setCurrentItemIndex(currentItemIndex + 1);
   } else {
      clearInterval();
   }
}, 5000);
   
return (
    <div>
        <p> {items[currentItemIndex].name} <p>
    </div>
)
```

I want to update `currentItemIndex` every 5 seconds so the `div` shows next item, and if it reaches the end, it should start over: `0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 ...`.

The problem is: it loops correctly the first time, but after reaching the end, it shows the first item for a fraction of a second and then goes to the last item: `0, 1, 2, 0 (really quick to) 2`.

What I'm doing wrong?
*I searched for this, but every article is talking about "how to prevent infinite loops", not "how to use them"!*

Comment: instead of `setCurrentItemIndex(currentItemIndex + 1)` can you try `setCurrentItemIndex( val => (val  + 1))`

Comment: you need to use `useEffect` to handle effects like `setTimeout` - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542264/how-to-setinterval-for-every-5-second-render-with-react-hook-useeffect-in-react

Comment: First, your use of [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) is incorrect and doesn't do anything. Second, your loop will never start back at the begining as you never reset your counter.

Comment: you need something that will move `currentItemIndex` back to zero and then you can keep increamenting it again. So for that you can add check like this `setCurrentItemIndex((currentItemIndex + 1) % items.length);`

Comment: @SaadMehmood Nice idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `useEffect` and with `setTimeout` like this:

```js
const items = [{ name: "item 0" }, { name: "item 1" }, { name: "item 2" }];

const App = () => {
  const [currentItemIndex, setCurrentItemIndex] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(
      () => setCurrentItemIndex((currentItemIndex + 1) % items.length),
      1000
    );
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id); // removes React warning when gets unmounted
    };
  }, [currentItemIndex]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p> {items[currentItemIndex].name} </p>
    </div>
  );
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems with this logic that you created.

First of all, `clearInterval` needs to be provided a variable that you created when creating the `setInterval` function (as you can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)), so this `clearInterval()` is doing nothing.

Besides that, you do not want to clear your timer when `currentItemIndex` reaches its threshold, but instead you want it to go back to zero.

In React, we usually use `useEffect` for timing events as you need to clear them on unmount so you don't keep them running after your component is unmounted. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(yourFunction);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach if you want to. You create a function using which will set state after 5 seconds using timeout. Once the state is set you again call the same method.
For sake of react you call this method once using useEffect.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const items = [{ name: "item 0" }, { name: "item 1" }, { name: "item 2" }];


export default function App() {
  const [currentItemIndex, setCurrentItemIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    incrementAfterDelay(1000, 1, 2);
  }, []);

  const incrementAfterDelay = (delay, step, lastStep) => {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        setCurrentItemIndex((value) => {
          return (value < lastStep)? value + step : 0
        }, incrementAfterDelay(delay, step, lastStep)),
      delay
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p> {items[currentItemIndex].name} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```