# API response not updating after x seconds reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to automatically update a table - In my testing I log the output every 10 seconds however the response stays the same from the initial component render

```
componentDidMount() {       
    this.interval = setInterval(this.getData, 10000);
    this.getData()        
}

getData = () => {
    axios.get(`myApiUrl`)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ data: response.data.entries })
            console.log(response.data.entries)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

If I manually try to grab the data from postman every 10 seconds, the updated changes works fine.

Comment: What is the "change" you're expecting every 10 seconds? It looks like you're just making the exact same API request over and over, so results aren't gonna be different

Comment: The data is being updated from another source - I would like to see these changes reflected every 10 seconds. @Jayce444

Comment: your browser is probably caching the data, since the request hasn't changed. If you control the server for the API you might need to send the right response headers to ensure the browser doesn't cache it.

Comment: This is probably what you need (useEffect hook): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542264/how-to-setinterval-for-every-5-second-render-with-react-hook-useeffect-in-react

Comment: @RobinZigmond correct!

Answer (score 1):

@Robin Zigmond was correct

Updated the call to remove the cache

```
getData = () => {
        axios.get(`myApiUrl`, {
            headers: {
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',                
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ data: response.data.entries })
                console.log(response.data.entries)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
```