# React Natvie Countdown

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer, countdown

hi i am new with react native and javascript i would like to make a small countdown where you enter in the function a number and the type of countdown so now if i have selected seconds, minutes or hours in a dropdown and have in the textinput as example 10 i would enter an object like this in the function {count: '10', format: 'sec'} does anyone of you have a good example what could help me with this maybe?

```
   const startCountDown = (countdownObj) => {
 setCountdownRunnning(true);
 //countdownObj.count = 10
 //countdownObj.format (sec, min, h)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should read about intervals in JS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval
After you need read how to use setInterval in React:
https://medium.com/@garethdavisrogers/using-setinterval-and-clearinterval-with-react-hooks-7fcf26dc8fdb
Here you can get interval example in React Native:
[How to setInterval for every 5 second render with React hook useEffect in React Native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542264/how-to-setinterval-for-every-5-second-render-with-react-hook-useeffect-in-react)

Good luck.